# Understanding of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Just wanted to clarify my understanding of independent random variables.  Say, (U,V) are random variables s.t.
U=the number of trials needed for the first head and
V=the number of trials needed for the second head

If I want to explain that its not independent, is the reason that in this case the number of trials for one random variable depends on the other?  What I mean is that if it takes 1 trial to get one head and 2 trials for two heads, then that first head contributes to the latter variable.  Is my understanding correct, or should it be more mathematical instead?

Comment: And you're using a single coin for both variables?

Comment: yes.  only one coin.

Answer (score 2):

One way to demonstrate a lack of independence is to show a relationship between $U$ and $V$. For example, if we can observe $u$ then we can restrict the range of possible values of the observed $v$. Specifically,
$$
U=u\implies V\geq u+1.
$$
This means that the conditional distribution of $V$ given $U=u$ is not the same as the marginal distribution of $V$. The former has support $\{u+1,u+2,\ldots\}$ whereas the latter $\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$. If $U$ and $V$ were independent, these two distributions would coincide, in particular, they would have the same support for every $u$ such that $P(U=u)\ne0$.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the edit!

Comment: My pleasure. (+1 for the answer.)